# Why am I getting recursion error?

Tags: python, sql, django

Why am I getting an error when trying to run my server to access the database to see if my code works?  While in my projects folder in `Terminal`, I ran `sudo python manage.py runserver` to try to run the server but it doesn't work because of the aforementioned error.  I've looked around SO but can't find one directly related to my problem.

I'm getting my `if()` statement is the problem.

The error I'm getting says:

```
RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object
```

Here's my `views.py` file:

```
from .models import Album
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse_lazy
from django.views import generic
from django.views.generic import View
from django.views.generic.edit import CreateView, UpdateView, DeleteView
from .forms import UserForm

class IndexView(generic.ListView):
    template_name = 'music/index.html'
    context_object_name = 'all_albums'

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Album.objects.all()

class DetailView(generic.DeleteView):
    model = Album
    template_name = 'music/detail.html'

class AlbumCreate(CreateView):
    model = Album
    fields = ['artist', 'album_title', 'genre', 'album_logo']

class AlbumUpdate(UpdateView):
    model = Album
    fields = ['artist', 'album_title', 'genre', 'album_logo']

class AlbumDelete(DeleteView):
    model = Album
    success_url = reverse_lazy('music:index')

class UserFormView(View):
    form_class = UserForm
    template_name = 'music/registration_form'

    # display blank form
    def get(self, request):
        form = self.form_class(None)
        return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': form})

    def post(self):
        form = self.form_class(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            user = form.save(commit=False)

            #cleaned normalized data

            username = form.cleaned_data['username']
            password = form.cleaned_data['password']

            user.set_password(password)
            user.save()
```

Tail of error:

```
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Django-1.11.2-py2.7.egg/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 255, in check
    warnings.extend(check_resolver(pattern))
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Django-1.11.2-py2.7.egg/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 26, in check_resolver
    return check_method()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Django-1.11.2-py2.7.egg/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 172, in check
    warnings = self._check_pattern_startswith_slash()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Django-1.11.2-py2.7.egg/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 140, in _check_pattern_startswith_slash
    regex_pattern = self.regex.pattern
```

Here's my `forms.py` file:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django import forms

class UserForm(forms.ModelForm): # UserForm inherits from forms.
    passwords = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput)

    class Meta: # Information about your class.
        model = User # whenevr a creates sign up to your site it's gonna go in same table
        fields = ['username', 'email', 'password']
```

Here's my `urls.py` file:

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

app_name = 'music'

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^music/', include('music.urls'))
]

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root = settings.STATIC_ROOT)
    urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Comment: I know that a recursion traceback can be long, but can we have the tail of it please? All lines from the end upwards that don't repeat.

Comment: maybe you override UserForm save method? can you put the code here?

Comment: @MartijnPieters posted

Comment: Could you also post your urls.py?

Comment: You missed the .html in your template name

Comment: @DiegoPuente posted.

Comment: @FazilZaid posted.

Comment: @bojack: you didn't post your `urls.py`, you reposted the form.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Apologies for the careless mistake, it's fixed now.

Comment: I got this recursion error when I passed my project name in urls.py instead of my app name.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't pass `request` into your `post` method, It should be,

```
class UserFormView(View):
    form_class = UserForm
    template_name = 'music/registration_form.html' 


    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        # blaah
```

Also, missed the extension of your template.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use FormView for this and don't need to override post or get method in your View, Because you will get form object in template if user assign form_class in View.You have to override form_valid() method for your custom operations

```
class UserFormView(FormView):
    form_class = UserForm
    template_name = 'music/registration_form'

    def form_valid(self, form)
        user = form.save(commit=False)
        username = form.cleaned_data['username']
        password = form.cleaned_data['password']
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save()
```